# Why does matching a Result require an explicit Err when changing the type of the Result?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have a match expression that I would like to potentially return an error from. It seems that the compiler is not able to infer that the last case `e` is an `Err(String)` and requires the pattern to be explicit:

```
fn foo() -> Result<Option<u8>, String> {
    unimplemented!() // don't mind the panic here
}

fn foo2() -> Result<u8, String> {
    let bar = foo();

    for _ in 0..3 {
        let baz = match bar {
            Ok(Some(b)) => b,
            Ok(None)    => continue,
            Err(e)      => return Err(e) // works
//          e           => return e      // error[E0308]
        };
    }

    Ok(0)
}

fn main() {
    let _ = foo2();
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:33
   |
13 |           e           => return e      // error[E0308]
   |                                 ^ expected u8, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<u8, _>`
              found type `std::result::Result<std::option::Option<u8>, _>`
```

I'm pretty sure I have exhausted all the `Ok(_)` variants, so the only one left should be `Err(_)`. This error doesn't occur if `foo()` returns `Result<u8, String>`, for instance. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `Err` is not a type.

`Err` is a variant of `Result<T, E>` whose type is `Result<T, E>`. Since `Result<T, E>` is different from `Result<U, E>` unless `T == U`, and since there is no implicit conversion, you need to explicitly perform the conversion.

I admit it does look silly since type inference takes care of deducing the `T`, `U`, and `E` in this case resulting in `Err(e) => return Err(e)`, but at the semantic level those 2 `Err(e)` have different types.

For another silly example:

```
enum Term<'a> {
    Int(i64),
    String(&'a str),
}

fn staticify(t: Term) -> Term<'static> {
    use Term::*;

    match t {
        String(_) => String("Hello, World!"),
        _ => t,
    }
}
```

Will fail for the same reason, because `Term<'a>` and `Term<'static>` are not the same type unless `'a == 'static`. When `Term` contains mostly non-lifetime parameters it gets tedious :(

Answer (score 3):

Things will be clearer if you use qualified types for your `Err(e) => return Err(e)` case. What you are really saying here is:

```
Result<Option<u8>, String>::Err(e) => return Result<u8, String>::Err(e)
```

Once written like this, it becomes clear that there is a conversion going on. Conversely, `e => return e` is equivalent to:

```
Result<Option<u8>, String>::Err(e) => return Result<Option<u8>, String>::Err(e)
```

which has the wrong type since your function is supposed to return `Result<u8, String>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are matching `Result<Option<u8>, String>`, so `e` is of this type but your function requires the return value to be the type of `Result<u8, String>`:

```
note: expected type `std::result::Result<u8, _>`
         found type `std::result::Result<std::option::Option<u8>, _>`
```